# Corrupt pdf attachment with PHPMailer

Tags: php, pdf, phpmailer, email-attachments

I'm attempting to convert a png to pdf then email it as an attachment. The conversion works fine, but when I attempt to email the resulting pdf it gets corrupted. Using the code (Some information removed) below the `image.pdf` is good but the attachment is corrupt. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
require_once 'class.phpmailer.php';

$data = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $_POST['imgBase64']);
$data = str_replace(' ', '+', $data);
$img = new Imagick();
$img->readImageBlob(base64_decode($data));
$img->setImageFormat('pdf');
file_put_contents('image.pdf', $img->getImageBlob());
$pdf = base64_encode($img->getImageBlob());

$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'webmaster@***';
$email->FromName  = '***';
$email->Subject   = 'Subject';
$email->Body      = "Sent from http://www.example.com.\n\nDo not reply.";
$email->AddAddress('***@***.com');
$email->addStringAttachment($pdf, 'form.pdf', 'base64', 'application/pdf');
if(!$email->Send())
  trigger_error("Failed to send email. {$email->ErrorInfo}", E_USER_ERROR);
?>
```

Comment: phpmailer does the base64 for you. you provide an ORIGINAL string, it takes care of the rest. that means your email is going out with a double-encoded pdf. in other words, eliminate the `$pdf = base64_encode(...)` business. all you need is `addStringAttachment($img->getImageBlob,...)`

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.